# Removing next Element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, removeclass, removechild

The button is on this TR and i can easily remove it with the following code. How do i remove the NEXT TR

E.g.

```
<TR></TR> --> Code works with removing this
<TR></TR> --> Remove the next TR THis one

var $this = $(this),
orderTr = $this.parents('tr');
orderTr.remove();
```

Comment: Come on now. This is among the most basic operations in jQuery. Couldn't you at least visit the API docs and type "next" into the search bar? http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like

```
 $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
```

or

```
$(this).parents("tr").next().remove();
```